# xcode Player.center shows error : property "center" not found on object of type "SKSpritenode"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

When i try to set center on my SKSpritenode, it shows an error. i can use position but thats not the right way to accomplish what i want. Any ideas on what to use instead? Or how to use .center on a node?

```
player.center = CGPointMake(player.center.x, player.center.y - BirdFly); // Shows error that i put in title
BirdFly = BirdFly - 5;

if (BirdFly < -15){
    BirdFly = -15;
}

if (BirdFly > 0){
    player.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"flappy1"];



}
if (BirdFly < 0){
    player.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"flappy5"];
}
```

}

Comment: There is no such a property called center for SKSpriteNode or SKNode.

Comment: @ElTomato Well what should i use instead

Comment: There is a position property ... also there is an anchorPoint which defines how texture is positioned (drawn) relatively to the node.

Comment: did you still need help with this?